# Methods of proving $X_n \to 0$ a.s. using moments of $X_n$

Tags: probability-theory

I am interested in knowing methods of proving $X_n \to 0$ a.s. using moments of $X_n$. One such simple method is to use Borel Cantelli lemma/Markov inequality. I want to know is there any other method

Comment: Do you have any specific application in mind?

Comment: @saz: in machine learning such techniques are needed.